# Gsuite Add-on: can a user also (individually) remove an add-on when individual install is enabled?

Tags: gsuite-addons

We have enabled individual install for a newly developed Google Forms add-on.

- An individual user can install the addon, but cannot uninstall/delete this add-on once they decide they no longer need this add-on. Is this common behaviour?
- When the user searches for this Marketplace app they will see the 'delete' button, but this button is not active

Extra info:
the add-on (marketplace app) is whitelisted in our Google domain

Answer (score 0):

- Enabling individual install allows a user to remove an Add-on he previously installed himself.
- Enabling individual install does NOT allow the user to unistall an Add-on that has been installed domain-wide by the admin.
- If you want the user to decide himself either he wants an Add-on or not, you as an Admin should not install an Add-on domain-wide - be it your own or a commercial Add-on.

[image]